# Melhor forma de fazer uma consulta ao banco usando LINQ e Entity Framework

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, linq

Olá! Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados, o cenário é o seguinte: recebo `email` e partir dele busco o `id` do usuário. Sobre o banco, há a tabela `Contact`, a qual tem relacionamento NxN com a tabela `user`. Até o momento fiz da seguinte forma:

```
var result = _context
             .Clients
             .Where(x => x.Contacts.First().Email.Equals(email))
             .AsNoTracking()
             .ToList();
            
var id = result
         .Select(x => x.Id)
         .First()
         .ToString();
```

Porém, acho que nessa consulta que fiz poderia estar sendo prolixo, podendo ser feita de uma maneira melhor, até mesmo em uma única consulta ao banco (fiz 2 nesse exemplo). Alguém poderia dar alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parte que você pega o Email do primeiro item da tabela de contatos eu não posso afirmar se está certo ou errado, pois isso depende muito do negócio do seu sistema, ou seja, somente você poderia afirmar se isso está correto.

Vou partir do pressuposto que isso esteja correto, que o email é sempre o primeiro da tabela de contatos (apesar de não fazer sentido na minha cabeça) e vou alterar para ser apenas um LINQ.

```
var result = _context.Clients.Where(w => w.Contacts.First().Email.Equals(email))
                             .Select(s => s.Id)
                             .FirstOrDefault();

string id = result == null ? string.Empty : result.ToString();
```

Você não estava fazendo duas consultas no banco como havia dito, pois na parte 1, onde você fazia o `.ToList()`, já trouxe todos os dados do banco que atendem o seu critério definido no `.Where()` para a memória. Porém você está com todos os campos dessa tabela de clientes em memória, sendo que só precisa do `Id`, sem contar que trouxe mais de 1 registro, sendo que no fim você precisa só de 1 (pelo fato de usar o First).

Dessa forma que eu adicionei o código, você busca apenas o `Id` para a memória e apenas 1 registro.

Espero ter ajudado!